# could not find function "setup"

Tags: command-line

i get following error ; my seurat version :3.1.5 ; my R version 3.2.7 ; i run this code in Rstudio

```
library(Seurat)
library(useful)
nbt.data=read.table("a.txt",sep=",",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
nbt.data=log(nbt.data+1)

corner(nbt.data)
         Hi_2338_1  Hi_2338_2 Hi_2338_3 Hi_2338_4 Hi_2338_5 A1BG      2.310553 0.00000000  0.000000 1.0116009         0 A1BG-AS1  0.000000 0.00000000  1.497388 0.3074847         0 A1CF      0.000000 0.04879016  0.000000 0.0000000         0 A2LD1     0.000000 0.00000000  0.000000 0.2546422         0 A2M       0.000000 0.00000000  0.000000 0.0000000         0

dim(nbt.data) [1] 23730   301

nbt=new("seurat",raw.data=nbt.data)

nbt=setup(nbt,project="NBT",min.cells = 3,names.field = 2,names.delim = "_",min.genes = 1000,is.expr=1,) 
Error in setup(nbt, project = "NBT", min.cells = 3, names.field = 2, names.delim = "_",  : could not find function "setup"
```

Comment: Why ask here?  Your `r-base` package doesn't match any supported release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=r-base) and it looks more like a programming question

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base` to the question by editing it. How did you installed R on this system?

Comment: i am sorry my R version is  3.6.3 . i say my question false?

Comment: Did you find a solution for me?